# Can I use AWS kinesis for data upsert or transformation?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have 3 different csv files coming every 5–10 secs each and I want to merge those csv files into one based on some update condition for near real time reporting. My current system involves pushing files from s3 to redshift every 10 sec but not able to achieve desired speed to combine the table.

Comment: You want to consume `csv` records for 5-10 seconds and then combine them to a single `csv` by some logic? How big are these `csv`s? Where do you push the combined `csv`?

Comment: @johni - it turns out I cannot run update in AWS Kinesis analytics. That was my main intention of using kinesis analytics.